# Remote IP address varies when client is tethered over cell

Tags: php, ip, network-protocols, cellular-network

I am building a solution in php which requires me to accurately know the ip of the requestor.  For most cases, the classic call to

`$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];`

works just fine.

However, I've noted that in the case where the client is making their request over a tethered connection, I get a completely different address than what google and my firewall report.

I can verify this on the client (tethered) side by searching for ["my ip"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my%20ip%22) on google which gives me an IP that matches what my server's firewall is reporting as well.  Neither of these match what the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` contains on the server side though.

My questions then are:

- Why do these addresses differ in general?
- How do I get to the ip address that my firewall and google see, specifically using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, turns out this was being done using a javascript "feature" (what I'd think about calling a vulnerability instead) all along.  Scary stuff, as it also exposes your internal IP address as well. Anyway it's something called WebRTC, that just started getting a lot of attention this week as it's been officially implemented by firefox and chrome:

```
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    //firefox already has a default stun server in about:config
    //    media.peerconnection.default_iceservers =
    //    [{"url": "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]
    var servers = undefined;

    //add same stun server for chrome
    if(window.webkitRTCPeerConnection)
        servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate){

            //match just the IP address
            var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})/
            var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];

            //remove duplicates
            if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                callback(ip_addr);

            ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
        }
    };

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){});

    }, function(){});
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});
```

Source: https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

Demo: https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/

Answer (score 1):

Thast depends on your cell phone provider. More often than not, your phone gets an IP address from the private range and gets NATed when making connections "to the internet" - like most of home networks.

Unlike home networks, the provider's network may have several connections (gateways) to the internet. So potentially every connection you make can go over a different gateway. Thus you see a different address on different calls.

In these cases (networks with several uplinks), the routing rules may be quite complicated. So for example, the destination may play a role - the provider might be peering at several different places (network nodes) and choose the one closest to the destination. So you can have consistent sources regarding one destination, but a different one on another destination.

In any case, you cannot do anything with these addresses, as the provider won't allow any incoming connections.

Comment: Thank you, that all makes sense in theory and appreciate the quick answer! However, in practice I am seeing a consistent ip address coming through from this source when I look at Google and at my firewall. So there must be some means of obtaining this address other than $_SERVER['remote_ip'].  Any thoughts?

Comment: @matt The IP address you are seeing may depend on the connection between source and destination. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

They could well be using a proxy server which you would have no control over. The underlying client IP would not be visible if this were the case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but please reread my question. It is clearly visible via some means, since as I stated Google and Amazon are both reporting it with no problem.